# How to convert formatted math back to what it was originally?

Tags: support, mathjax

Just a quick question:
On math stack exchange, if I want to practice and understand the formatting, is there any way I can convert the formatted math back into what it was originally?
For example, instead of seeing $5x^2-5=0$, can I see the original text of 5x^2-5=0.

Comment: On a Mac, I hold down the "control" key while clicking on the math, and a menu comes up that leads me to the code behind the math.

Comment: For Firefox on Windows, I right-click the expression and choose "Show Math As" -> "TeX Commands" from the pop-up menu.

Comment: See also: [How to view LaTeX source of equations?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/659/how-to-view-latex-source-of-equations)

Comment: I usually just click *edit*, I find that faster than via context menu (but of course, you need to find where the formula is in the post and also you should take care not to click "save").

Comment: Ok... Thanks guys!